# Need more specific mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to exclude results from this basic query:

```
SELECT PageID, PlanID
FROM table
WHERE PlanID = 1 
AND PageID in !=0
```

This is a mapping table to join objects like blogs to tags, tags to images, etc..

My problem is there are other results that this query picks up on..

```
PlanID = 1 - PageID = 234 - OtherID = 0
PlanID = 1 - PageID = 234 - OtherID = 456
```

In reality this is what I want to write:

```
SELECT PageID, PlanID 
FROM table
WHERE PlanID = 1 
AND PageID !=0
AND OtherID = 0
AND OtherID = 0
AND OtherID = 0
AND OtherID = 0
AND OtherID = 0
```

I'd like to not have to write numerous 'OtherID's = 0' over and over,
As this is a dynamic query and 'PageID' could be any one of the 'OtherID's.

Is there a way to exclude all the 'OtherID's with out having to write them out,
Or having to do some type of dynamics in my code that switches the !=0 ID with the 'OtherID's = 0

Something like:

```
SELECT PageID, PlanID 
FROM table
WHERE PlanID = 1 
AND PageID !=0
AND AllOtherFields = 0
```

How can I either request a distinct query that JUST says pageID !=0 and planID =1
Or just Zero-out all of fields that I'm not looking for..?

Comment: Could you post the actual table structure you're working with? I'm confused by the _pageID could be any one of the other IDs_ part...

Comment: PageID is an argument variable passed to the function. at any point in time I'm trying to find 2 objects that are joined, that also has a planID of 1. so the issue I'm having is writing out all the other fieldnames and making sure they are equal to 0. I don't want to have to write out the other field names.. I'd prefer to have a more distinct query that ignores the other field names in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT PageID, PlanID
FROM table
WHERE PlanID = 1 and
      PageID <> 0 and
      OtherId <> 0
```

Note:  you can use either `!=` or `<>`.  They are equivalent.

If you want to check that all other fields are 0, you can do something like:

```
SELECT PageID, PlanID
FROM table
WHERE PlanID = 1 and
      PageID <> 0 and
      0 not in (OtherId1, otherid2, otherid3, . . . )
```

Comment: Yes, the above does work as I want.. BUT, it's still forcing me to write the fieldnames out.

0 not in (OtherId1, otherid2, otherid3, . . . )
is the same as 
AND OtherID =0
AND OtherID =0
AND OtherID =0

Comment: @Kusanagi . . . Yes, you have to write the fields out.  If that's a problem, do something like `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table'`, dump the results into Excel, format them with commas, and create the query from that string.